AG-Grid columnDef should come from backend?
Im starting using AG-Grid in a React + NestJS + postgress application.
currently im have mockup data for AG-Grid but i will start returning data from backend but im not sure what should be the best way to format ColumnDef, ATM i just have this in my frontend:
const colDefs: ColDef<IRow>[] = [
    { field: 'name' },
    { field: 'email' },
    { field: 'phone' },
    { field: 'address' },
    { field: 'zip_code' },
    { field: 'registryDate' },
];

and similar structure for Rows, but since the data will start coming from the backend how should i handle the ColumDefs?
should that be included in the backend response something like:
return {
 colDefs: [
    { field: 'name' },
    { field: 'email' },
    { field: 'phone' },
    { field: 'address' },
    { field: 'zip_code' },
    { field: 'registryDate' },
 ],
 rowData: [
    {
        name: 'Jon Doe',
        email: 'jon.doe@example.com',
        phone: '+1 312778498',
        address: '',
        zip_code: '',
        registryDate: '',
    },
 ],
}

or should i continue using the frontend data as it is?
Since i will need to add extra properties like valueFormatter and other similar properties im not sure what should be the best way to handle this.
i google about this but did find a solution to my question
